# Number of relations on a set of $n$ elements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-number-of-distinct-relations-on-a-finite-set

> From the link above I'm having trouble understanding how from $n^2$ ordered pairs which are either true or false there are a total of $ {2^{n^2}} $, would it not be $2n$?

Also, can someone explain the subset part of the definition, say I have a set $\{a,b,c\}$, would that mean $\{(a,b), (b,a), (c,c)\}$ is also a relation? Or is are the subsets only the pairs of elements of $\{a,b,c\}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by an "order relation" in this context but $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$ in the relation mean that it can't be used to order $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is correct. Every relation is a subset of $X\times X$ which has power $n^2$. But the number of subsets in a set with $k$ elements is $2^k$, so in our case $2^{n^2}$.

Yes, the set $\{(a,b), (b,a), (c,c)\}$ is a subset of $X\times X$ and thus a relation (which is symmetric).

Comment: So {(a,b),(b,a),(c,c)} would be a relation?

Comment: Yes,and symmetric.

Comment: Thank you, this all makes sense now.